# Python can't import shapely

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, geos, shapely

I am using Python3.4 on Mac OSX and I am trying to import shapely. I am however unable to do so. Here is my traceback:

```
    from shapely.geometry import Point
  File "/Users/tc9/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/shapely/geometry/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .base import CAP_STYLE, JOIN_STYLE
  File "/Users/tc9/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/shapely/geometry/base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from shapely.coords import CoordinateSequence
  File "/Users/tc9/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/shapely/coords.py", line 8, in <module>
    from shapely.geos import lgeos
  File "/Users/tc9/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/shapely/geos.py", line 74, in <module>
    _lgeos = load_dll('geos_c', fallbacks=alt_paths)
  File "/Users/tc9/Library/Python/3.4/lib/python/site-packages/shapely/geos.py", line 53, in load_dll
    libname, fallbacks or []))
OSError: Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants ['/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/Current/GEOS', '/opt/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib']
```

I think I might have to set the GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH, but I'm not sure what to set it to.

Here is an ls of `/Users/tc9/homebrew/Cellar/geos/3.4.2/lib` after I did brew install geos:

```
libgeos-3.4.2.dylib
libgeos.dylib
libgeos_c.a
libgeos.a
libgeos_c.1.dylib
libgeos_c.dylib
```

I edited and sourced my `~/.profile`, but that didn't solve things:

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH="/Users/tc9/homebrew/Cellar/geos/3.4.2"
export GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Can anybody point me in the direction of a solution for getting shapely to import? Thanks.

Comment: What is your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`? And is there a `libgeos_c.dylib` in `/opt/local/lib`?

Comment: `/Users/tc9/homebrew/Cellar` may be where brew store things, but it uslaly makes a symbolic link to some more practical directory (without the `Cellar` directory. Do you know which directory is that?

Comment: @Evert echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH yields a blanks line. I have not set my DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. The folder /opt/local/bin exists, but /opt/local/lib doesn't. Doing find / -name "libgeos_c.dylib" yields /Users/tc9/homebrew/Cellar/geos/3.4.2/lib/libgeos_c.dylib and /Users/tc9/homebrew/lib/libgeos_c.dylib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set homebrew to install things in your home directory (well, the `homebrew` subdirectory in your home directory). That's ok, but you'll have to tell your system to find the installed libraries there. `/opt/local/lib` is commonly found automatically, but `/Users/tc9/homebrew/lib` won't.

So instead of setting `GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH`, try setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` as follows:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/tc9/homebrew/lib
```

You can do this on the command line first, and if it works, put it in your profile.

Note that I'm not using the `Cellar` subdirectory; you should see that as an archive for homebrew, but not as the actual files in use. For that, use `/home/tc9/homebrew` (with `lib`, `bin` etc appended). So for example, your `PATH` should also not include the `Cellar` directory.