# Ubuntu, Anaconda: Cannot import python shapely package

Tags: python, ubuntu, importerror, anaconda, shapely

[Shapely Import problem Related to MAC OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761682/python-cant-import-shapely)

I installed shapely using `sudo apt-get install python-shapely`.

I am using `Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)|` with `ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bit)`

After successful installation, when I try to import it from `ipython` it gives me an import error. `ImportError: No module named shapely`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because `apt-get` installs packages to the system default python, under `/usr/python2.7/lib/site-packages`. Anaconda has its own package manager, [`conda`](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/intro.html), which you might want to use in your case. `conda install shapely` should do the trick.

Comment: Im having similiar issue, but with requests, I do conda install requests, no avail.

Comment: @DavidCrook It has to work, if you use python 2.7 or 3.3-3.5. What is the output of `conda search requests`?